# Replace line comment(//) to block comment(/*) regex JS

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to get a regex to replace all line comments to block comments, but I want to return only legal js comments and not `//` that is part of a string for that I have to detect if `//` is in quotes and not replace it.

Now I got something like this `/"(.*?\/\/.*?)"/`, but it replaces the opposite - all `//` in quotes and not the ones without.

```
// Change heading:
```

should match

```
document.getElementById("myH").innerHTML = "My First //Page";
```

shouldn't match

```
document.getElementById("myP").innerHTML = "My first paragraph."; // Change paragraph:;
```

should match

```
console.log("some important info //shouldn't replace"); // this is important info
```

In this case, valid comment should match, but comment inside quotation marks shouldn't.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Match the comments with [`/(?:(?=["'][^"']*$)|(?=^[^"']*\/\/.*$))(.*?)\/\/(.*)/gm`](https://regex101.com/r/8VuufA/1) and replace with `$1/*$2*/`.

```js
let code = `// Change heading:
document.getElementById("myH").innerHTML = "My First Page";
document.getElementById("myP").innerHTML = "My first paragraph.";  // Change paragraph:

console.log("some important info //shouldn't replace"); // this is important info
console.log('some important info //should not replace'); // this is important info`;

code = code.replace(/(?:(?=["'][^"']*$)|(?=^[^"']*\/\/.*$))(.*?)\/\/(.*)/gm, "$1/*$2*/");
console.log(code);
```